# How to use translate() with 2 digit numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner Python programmer. I am trying to turn each letter of the alphabet into their corresponding numbers (a=1, b=2...). I have tried using re.sub but since I can only substitute one character at a time, it requires 26 passes to translate just one character. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look up the function `ord`.

Comment: May be `dict(zip(range(1,27),string.ascii_letters))`?

Comment: `dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1))` - https://repl.it/@lobopt/PeriodicGuiltyMalware

Comment: ... or `','.join(x for x in map(lambda x: (ord(x) - 96) % 26), string))`. Tons of other ways, too.